# WCF client hangs on any operation after awaiting async operation in Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, console-application

Client example code:

```
var f = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(new Callback(), "NetTcpBinding_Name");
f.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
f.Open();
IService s = f.CreateChannel();
Console.WriteLine("Lock status: " + s.IsUserLocked(id));
Task task = s.LockUserAsync(id);
Console.Write("Sent, awaiting ");
Console.WriteLine(task);
await task;
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.WriteLine("Lock status: " + s.IsUserLocked(id)); // never returns, timeout
```

After awaiting on an async method `LockUserAsync` any sync methods hang forever. The debugger shows that `IsUserLocked` is actually called second time and reached its return.

It doesn't affect other clients: they can connect and repeat the same thing from start.

Behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
  ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallback))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task LockUserAsync(int userId);
    [OperationContract]
    int IsUserLocked(int id);
}

public interface IServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void TestCallback(); // not used
}
```

Both methods are just placeholders:

```
public async Task LockUserAsync(int id)
{
    return;
}

public int IsUserLocked(int id)
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

Update: it's a console application so no synchronization context. If I replace `await` with `.Wait()` it works. `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't change anything.

I've found that the continuation is somehow directly called from `Task.SetResult`. Why it's not invoked through `ThreadPool`?

Comment: In a Console application the `Main` method cannot be `async` so eventually you are going to have to call `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` inside this `Main` method in order to wait for all asynchronous methods to complete. Of course inside those `async` methods you can use the `await` keyword when calling the webservices.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, I'm already doing so otherwise it would not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is no `SynchronizationContext` like with ConsoleApplication TPL tries to optimize things by invoking continuations directly from `Task.TrySetResult`. Since my code calls WCF back from continuation it causes a deadlock inside external WCF code.

The solution was to put `await Task.Yield();` after each `await s.WcfMethod();` which causes next continuation to be invoked from `ThreadPool`.

Personally I think that it's a bug of WCF: it should call `Task.SetResult` inside `Task.Run()` or pass [TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to `TaskCompletionSource` settings.